# Copy files from my local filesystem to HDFS using Flume

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, flume-ng

Using a file generator in java, I will have a stream of directories and files in my local filesystem that I need to move in HDFS. I search in internet and i saw that i can use Flume, however I didn't find any resources that explains to me how to do that. Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Thank you

Comment: More details are required to be able to give you some hits. First of all, you have several machines or you are doing everything on the same node (for testing for example). What is the nature of the files: are those static files which you will read all at once or those are log files for example which are being created from time to time?

Comment: For now, i am using the same node for testing. It will be log files created by the user, and the interval between each creation can vary from minutes to hours. But now i am generating random files to see how HDFS will respond to the streaming of small files.

Answer (score 2):

I have never done it on the same machine (as you mentioned in you comment, about the environment), so you might need to do a few tests and adjustments for the following configuration to work.

In your case, since the files will be created dynamically in one(or many directories) I would suggest to configure the [Spooling Directory Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source)(per directory) and [HDFS Sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink). Create a file `test.conf` in `conf` directory in Flume installation folder and put similar configuration:

```
# Name the components on this agent
agent.sources = file-source
agent.sinks = hdfs-sink
agent.channels = mem-channel

# Associate channel with source and sink
agent.sources.file-source.channels = mem-channel
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = mem-channel

# Configure the source
agent.sources.file-source.type = spooldir
agent.sources.file-source.spoolDir = /tmp/spool/
agent.sources.file-source.fileHeader = true

# Configure the sink
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = /tmp/log.log
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = /flume/test/

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
agent.channels.mem-channel.type = memory
agent.channels.mem-channel.capacity = 1000
agent.channels.mem-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

To run the agent, execute the following command in the Flume installation directory:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n agent -c conf -f conf/test.conf
```

Start putting files into the `/tmp/spool/` and check if they are appearing in the HDFS.

When you are going to distribute the system I recommend using [Avro Sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#avro-sink) on client and [Avro Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#avro-source) on server, you will get it when you will be there.